# Control touch pad on a Chromebook

Tags: touchpad, chromebook

I'm finding the touchpad on the my new Chromebook to be less than stellar, and was excited to read about [a way to tweak its settings with `tpcontrol`](http://www.howtogeek.com/170648/10-commands-included-in-chrome-oss-hidden-crosh-shell/), hoping I could get it to work more like I would expect.

`tpcontrol`, however, is no longer available, and its replacement is also MIA:

```
crosh> tpcontrol
tpcontrol is deprecated. Please use inputcontrol instead.
crosh> inputcontrol
/usr/bin/crosh: line 801: /opt/google/input/inputcontrol: No such file or directory
```

Is there some other way to tweak the trackpad settings on a Chromebook?  Or some way to get one of these working?